# Setup a Tomcat server in Eclipse Oxygen 2

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server

Im new in using Eclipse. How to config a Tomcat server in Eclipse Oxygen 2 (4.7.2)? Im already browsing for tutorial, but nothing matches with my eclipse

Comment: what makes you think it's a world of difference with other versions of eclipse?

Comment: there are no server options in my "file ->new -> other.."

Comment: why should there be? Open the "servers" view, rightclick and select 'new'

Comment: 1 min of searching https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M5/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html
. Download external tomcat, than integrate in eclipse, nothing more.

Comment: *Which* Oxygen download did you get? Oxygen is a release *version*, it doesn't identify which combination of features you have, and it sounds like you have one that's lacking the Java EE tools. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=oxygen

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as yours. We downloaded the wrong IDE from eclipse.

The one we using(Eclipse IDE for Java Developers) will not have server for selection. Please try to download another one, Eclipse IDE for JAVA EE developers.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

[image: Eclipse Java EE]